# Find records which matches certain constrain based on NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql

There is a query which select some data. I'm creating a suppression table which would ignore the rows containing certain data.

```
suppression: occasion_id | days_before

   reminder: id | days_before | occasion_id
```

I'm making use of NOT EXIST to ignore selection of certain reminders.

The query is

```
SELECT id 
  from Reminder AS r 
 WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Suppression s 
                   WHERE s.occasion_id  = r.occasion_id  
                     AND s.days_before = r.days_before)

Reminder:1) 101| 1 |18
         2) 102| 7| 18

Suppresion: 18 | 1
```

The 1st reminder should be ignored and the 2nd one should be included.

As an example, if suppression table contain occasion_id - 18 and days_before- 1 the select should ignore reminder containing those data.

The sub query returns '1' in the case of 2nd reminder also. Why does it happens even if the statement after WHERE clause yields no result?

Comment: Think I misunderstood what you want. Could you give some sample datas (or better, a little sql fiddle), and show what you wanna retrieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining by the wrong condition.
Change the joining condition from `s.id = r.id` to `s.occasion_id = r.occasion_id`

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Reminder AS r 
inner JOIN Supression s ON s.occasion_id = r.occasion_id 
AND s.days_before <> r.days_before
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fd4e/9)

Your query also works.. Just change the joining condition

```
SELECT id 
  from Reminder AS r 
 WHERE NOT EXISTs (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Supression s 
                   WHERE s.occasion_id = r.occasion_id 
                     AND s.days_before = r.days_before)
```

Comment: My bad! I changed the model for more readability, but forgot to make relevant changes in query below.

Comment: The inner join method fails when an (18,7) added to suppression.The NOT EXIST works fine.

Comment: G One, thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish could be more easily done with a simple LEFT JOIN and an IS NULL in your where clause:

```
SELECT r.id 
FROM Reminder AS r 
LEFT JOIN Supression s ON s.id = r.id AND s.days_before = r.days_before
WHERE s.id IS NULL
```